# Netty with select and IO on current thread (selectNow based approach)?

Tags: netty

Apologies for the title but it's kind of difficult for me to summarize.

I'm searching for a way to have Netty select and handle only outstanding I/O events flagged for readiness on the current thread (or at least blocking the current thread) until complete; returning immediately if no events are present - effectively removing the internal thread model from Netty entirely and allowing me to control if and when the networking code paths execute.

This is super useful for performance in servers that operate on a "tick" based cycle (like game servers) because it allows them to skip an entire layer of queuing received messages between ticks.

I haven't been able to find explicit support, is this something that Netty can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported... Netty expect to "own" the `Selector`.